# Curl trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object

Tags: curl, paypal

I am working on an ecommerce site that uses paypal checkout, everything is working okay but inorder to save the transaction I have a PHP class that is used to handle PayPal API related operations but when I run the code I get this error:

```
Trying to get property 'access_token' of non-object in Paypalclass.php on line 29
```

Kindly assist, Here is my code:

```
class Paypal{
    public $paypalEnv       = 'production'; 
    public $paypalURL       = 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js';//https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/
    public $paypalClientID  = '##id##';
    private $paypalSecret   = '##secret##';

    public function validate($paymentID, $paymentToken, $payerID, $productID){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->paypalURL.'oauth2/token');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->paypalClientID.":".$this->paypalSecret);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if(empty($response)){
            return false;
        }else{
            $jsonData = json_decode($response);
            $curl = curl_init($this->paypalURL.'payments/payment/'.$paymentID);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $jsonData->access_token,
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/xml'
            ));
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            // Transaction data
            $result = json_decode($response);

            return $result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is this `$jsonData` you are attempting to access the property `access_token` on? Apparently you received nothing from PayPal or the `$response` wasn't decodable. Check your credentials and curl errors. Straightforward debugging is called for here.